# Can std::thread by used in an constructor initializer list?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm currently reading through the C++ Concurrency in Action book. I can't seem to get the following code to compile. I keep hitting the error

```
error: field of type 'std::thread' has private copy constructor
```

Is the copy constructor for std::thread being called?

```
class scoped_thread
{
    std::thread t;
public:
    explicit scoped_thread(std::thread t_):
        t(std::move(t_))
    {
        if(!t.joinable())
            throw std::logic_error("No thread");
    }
    ~scoped_thread()
    {
        t.join();
    }
    scoped_thread(scoped_thread const&)=delete;
    scoped_thread& operator=(scoped_thread const&)=delete;
};

int main() {
    int some_local_state = 0;
    scoped_thread t(std::thread(func(some_local_state)));
}
```

Comment: g++ 5.1.0: 0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))

Comment: Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0

Comment: Was it exactly the above code with an empty `main` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Is the copy constructor for std::thread being called?

It is totally up to the code which uses `scoped_thread`.

Note, that [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) is movable, but noncopyable type.

It means, that the next code works correctly:

```
scoped_thread st(std::thread{});
```

as `t_` is created via move constructor.

But if you create an instance of [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) and then try to wrap it into the `scoped_thread` like so:

```
std::thread t;
scoped_thread st(t);
```

then the attempt to call copy constructor happens and you get a compile error.

As `scoped_thread` seems to implement RAII the right way to use it is to wrap an unnamed instance of [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) as in the very first example of the answer.

Comment: The example shows it being called with:

`scoped_thread t(std::thread(func(some_local_state)));`

Comment: @NeuralSandwich the example is correct as `t` is created from rvalue.

Comment: Turns out I didn't have -std=c++11 set. So Clang wasn't using move semantics and fell back on copy constructor

Answer (score 0):

The listed code is correct. However `-std` was not set to `c++11` for the compiler. This *probably* left the compiler using the copy constructor as move semantics is not available in older C++ versions.

Comment: Most probably, move constructor is conditionally enabled by macro which depends on the standard used. If there is no move constructor, then copy constructor is used in order to construct the class from rvalue and the error happens.